# What is the difference between android-dhcp-9 and dhcpcd-5.5.6?

Tags: android, mobile, wifi, dhcp, ssid

i'm looking for ways to identify the devices connected to our wifi. we're all using android devices. only one mobile device has a device type of dhcpcd-5.5.6 and the rest are android-dhcp-9. i'm also wondering what the SSID 1 and SSID5 mean.